24 hours format with timepicker
I'm using timepicker.io to allow users to choose booking times. The working hours for bookings are from 22:00 to 05:00, which spans across midnight. I've tried configuring the timepicker with the options below, but it doesn't display the time slots correctly:
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '05:00',
    maxTime: '22:00'
});

When I changed it to the configuration below, the dropdown became blank:
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    minTime: '22:00',
    maxTime: '05:00'
});

How can I configure the timepicker to display the time slots correctly, considering the 24-hour format and the working hours spanning across midnight?

I think you need to manually create the time slots. Try this:
// Define the time slots
var timeSlots = [
    '22:00', '22:30', '23:00', '23:30',
    '00:00', '00:30', '01:00', '01:30', '02:00', '02:30',
    '03:00', '03:30', '04:00', '04:30', '05:00'
];

// Initialize the time picker
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true,
    disableTextInput: true
});

// Populate the time picker with custom time slots
$('#timepicker').on('click', function() {
    var timepicker = $(this).data('timepicker');
    var list = '';
    $.each(timeSlots, function(index, value) {
        list += '<li class="ui-timepicker-item" data-time="' + value + '">' + value + '</li>';
    });
    $('.ui-timepicker-list').html(list);
});

// Handle selection of custom time slots
$(document).on('click', '.ui-timepicker-item', function() {
    $('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', $(this).data('time'));
});

Hope that helps :)

doesn't work, when I write minTime: '22:00' maxTime: '05:00' it opens an empty dropdown

But that would mean 5am?

And I’m not sure timepicker.io ranges pass midnight natively. I still think a populated array needs to be created

Defining the time slots manually.

Just edited my answer, try now.

In this case, it only uses the default list from 00:00 to 23:30, not using the data provided by us

Have you tried it, manually entering the times you need?
